# Regex pattern for all chars and white space chars up until a double line break

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

With the following text:

```
** First Header
------------------------------------------------------------

(https://www.stackoverflow.com) Stack Overflow

Description: Stack Overflow

Google (https://www.google.com)

Description: Google


** Second Header
```

... how can I use a regex pattern that matches up until the second header with a double line break, so an output like:

```
** First Header
------------------------------------------------------------

(https://www.stackoverflow.com) Stack Overflow

Description: Stack Overflow

Google (https://www.google.com)

Description: Google
```

With the following regex (matching the first header with all characters as well as white space characters, hence the usages of `\s` and `\S` with the succeeding regex literals, and a negative lookahead of a double line break), I feel like I'm definitely on the right track:

```
RegExp("\\*\\* First Header[\\s\\S]*?(\\r?\\n(?!\\r?\\n))")
```

... but only outputs:

```
** First Header
```

Comment: Try `/(\*\* First Header[\s\S]*?)(?:\r?\n){3}/`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/EYwB1u/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew great, works dynamically as it should. Go ahead and post this as an answer instead, and I'll mark it as the best answer :-)

Comment: [Posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54581142/3832970) with explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/(\*\* First Header[\s\S]*?)(?:\r?\n){3}/
```

Or a JS regex only compatible

```
/(\*\* First Header[^]*?)(?:\r?\n){3}/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EYwB1u/1)

**Details**

- `(\*\* First Header[\s\S]*?)` - Group 1 capturing:

  - `\*\* First Header` - a literal `** First Header` substring
  - `[\s\S]*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?:\r?\n){3}` - three occurrences of an optional CR followed with LF chars (so, matching two blank lines in effect).

Answer (score 0):

The next regex will work:

`/\*[^]+?(?=\s+\*)/`

or

`RegExp("\\*[^]+?(?=\\s+\\*)")`

And it is the shortest way.

Comment: Never use `(\\s|.)+?` in any regex. It is a very inefficient construct that causes crashes, timeouts, etc. A dot can match any char depending on the regex flavor, flag, or can be successfully be replaced with identical constructs (e.g. `[^]` in JS). In NFA regex engines, `[\s\S]` can be used to simulate any char matching behavior.

Comment: Yes, in *this* case. With *this* string. But the input is a dynamic value.

Comment: Thanks for a hint. I removed that part. And now it is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be:

`RegEx("(\\*\\*[\\s\\S]*)(\\n\\n\\*\\*)")`

extracting the first group.

You can see the example in https://regex101.com/r/WPN83b/1